# I am using Selenium and test ng to validate if a url is returning 200 (success) or fail (501) error

Tags: selenium, testng

I am using Selenium and test ng to validate if a url is returning 200 (success) or fail (501) error.But i am getting null pointer exception. Please help me fix this.

Below are the codes

```
public void Test_Demo_Services() throws Exception {

              System.out.println("Entering Login test method");

          //Logging in
              this.oService = new WebService(this.oUrl.getSMHeartBeatUrl());
              Boolean     bbb=this.oService.checkWebService(this.oUrl.getSMHeartBeatUrl());


              System.out.println("Exiting Login test method");
       }
```

Webservices.java

```
public boolean checkWebService(String sUrl) throws Exception {      


       // Create Gson object (serialize and deserialize json strings)
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

              UrlBuilder oUrl = new UrlBuilder(sUrl);  //Base URL..no port     or anything needed

              //String sServiceUrl = oUrl.getWFMSVCActivitiesUrl();

              String sServiceUrl = oUrl.getSMHeartBeatUrl();

              //Create your http client
              CloseableHttpClient httpclient =     HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

              //Create http get object
              HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(sServiceUrl); 

              //getRequest.addHeader("WMT-UserId",this.getUserID());
              getRequest.addHeader("WMT-Security-ID", this.sAuthToken[0]);
              getRequest.addHeader("WMT-Token", this.sAuthToken[1]);

              //submit request and save response
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(getRequest);

              //get status code from response
              int sStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

              if(sStatusCode == 200 || sStatusCode == 201) {
              ReportResults("PASS", "getActivitiesAll webservice executed     successfully", false);

              return true;

              }
              else{
                     ReportResults("FAIL", "getActivitiesAll webservice     unsuccessful due to: " + this.getErrorMessage() , false);
                         this.setErrorMessage(response.getStatusLine().toString());
                     return false;

              }
```

Comment: i am getting error -----Boolean     bbb=this.oService.checkWebService(this.oUrl.getSMHeartBeatUrl());

Comment: Can you please share full code or stacktrace, cause from your code I am not able to understand which is user defined class, or which library you are using.

Comment: Which part of your code is Selenium? I see only HttpClient.

Comment: first part is selenium